# How can I change spacing between chapter and section but keep it the same for chapter and text?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir

So I need to have different spacing when chapter and section goes one after another, without text in between. So it should look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{15mm}
\setbeforesecskip{15mm}
\setaftersecskip{15mm}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter 1}
% here 10mm
\section{Chapter 1 Section 1}
% here 15mm
text.
But if section goes without a chapter before:
% here 15mm
\section{Chapter 1 Section 2}
% here 15mm
text.
And the same for chapters.
% From new page
\chapter{Chapter 2}
%here 15mm.
text.
%here 15mm.
\section{Chapter 2. Section 1.}
%here 15mm.
text.

\end{document}
```

The closest that I found was setting negative `\vspace{}` between chapter and section.
Is there a better way to do it, but not manually for every occurrence?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  since \chapter` and `\section` are defined in the document class, it's necessary to know which one you are using in order to offer any reliable suggestions.  If you can make your code into a compilable example, that should be good enough.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, sorry, I thought it was enough to put it in the tags.

Comment: The identification of `memoir` in the tags is a good thing, but the inclusion of a compilable example, which can be copied directly by potential helpers is much more important, since then it isn't necessary to "invent" anything, possibly incorrectly, thus wasting effort and resulting in irrelevant and useless answers.  Thank you for adding that.